# Get OneDrive Item Id for Current Word doc in a group drive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I'm working on a `Office.js` `Word` addin but document is stored on group drive.
How can i get either or all of `group id` , `drive id` and `item id` for current document

Related question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43531968/1859367)

But solution didn't work for me as it is for personal drive

### Current Solution

I have a solution but i'm not sure it is sound

The url I get in [getFilePropertiesAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfilepropertiesasync) is in following format

`<siteUrl>/sites/<groupnamelikestring>/Shared Documents/<pathtodoc>`

- `siteUrl` : Its a site url like `https://abc.sharepoint.com`
- `groupnamelikestring` : Not quite group name but something similar where some special characters are removed and everything in lowercase.
- `pathtodoc` : This is path to document in drive and share point.

#### 1. Get Group object

By using following `URL` i can get group object

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=mailNickName eq '<groupnamelikestring>'`

This returns required group but I'm not quite sure about `mailNickName` property

1. Is it guaranteed that `groupnamelikestring` === `mailNickName`?
2. what happens when group name gets renamed?
3. what happens if `mailNickName` updated using `PATCH` call

Is `groupnamelikestring` === `mailNickName` is sound?

#### 2. Getting `Drive Id` and `Item ID`

It is straight forard once we have group object. Using following `URL` we can get both `Drive Id` and `Item ID`.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/drive/root:/<pathtodoc>`

Here

- `groupid` : THis is group ID we got in previous step
- `pathtodoc` : This is path to document we git from document url.